# I can't compile sass and reload in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

[image]
**When I saved on changed two or three time it worked just fine, but when I saved changed more than three time then this error happened . It a terrible situation created when I try to compile sass and reload in browser
How do I solved this **

> Please help me to solved that .
>   I add the source gulpfile.js code
>   and also error result. so let me solved that

```js
ASUS@DESKTOP-U34ESKM MINGW64 ~/Desktop/front/project-1
$ gulp start
[11:28:09] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\front\project-1\gulpfile.js
[11:28:09] Starting 'browser-sync'...
[11:28:10] Finished 'browser-sync' after 308 ms
[11:28:10] Starting 'start'...
[11:28:10] Finished 'start' after 78 μs
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.1.109:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 --------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
[11:28:23] Starting 'sass'...
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (style.compile.css)
[11:28:23] Finished 'sass' after 125 ms
[11:28:48] Starting 'sass'...
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (style.compile.css)
[11:28:48] Finished 'sass' after 96 ms
[11:29:01] Starting 'sass'...
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (style.compile.css)
[11:29:01] Finished 'sass' after 73 ms
[11:29:09] Starting 'sass'...
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (style.compile.css)
[11:29:09] Finished 'sass' after 80 ms
[11:29:26] Starting 'sass'...

events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: sass\main.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: abstracts/base.
        on line 1 of sass/main.scss
>> @import 'abstracts/base';
   ^

    at options.error (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\front\project-1\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at DestroyableTransform.onerror (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\front\project-1\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:558:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at onwriteError (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\front\project-1\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:449:12)
    at onwrite (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\front\project-1\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:470:11)
    at WritableState.onwrite (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\front\project-1\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:180:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.afterTransform (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\front\project-1\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:93:3)
    at errorM (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\front\project-1\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:118:12)
    at Object.callback (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\front\project-1\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:127:16)
    at options.error (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\front\project-1\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:294:32)
```

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');


//Static server
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });

    gulp.watch('sass/abstracts/*.scss', ['sass']);
});


//Compile sass and inject browser
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    
        return gulp.src("sass/main.scss")
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(rename('style.compile.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())

});

gulp.task('start',['browser-sync']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and use `gulp-wait`, it inserts a additional delay before calling the next function in the chain. So the changes can be deducted.

Reference https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress/issues/731

Example usage

```
  return gulp.src("sass/main.scss")
        .pipe(wait(500))
        .pipe(sass())
```

Comment: It works but when I try to save my file three time almost instantly then it says can't import somethings like that. I can compile but it need to that save after 2s later . Why is that? Can you help me.